# Server gets incredibly slow when running Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#, windows

I'm attempting to run **Selenium (Chrome)** test on 2 servers, each running **Windows Server 2019 Standard (with GUI)**.

The first server (the one with the worst specs) has the following specs:

[image: server 1]

It runs Selenium perfectly fine, and can easily run 4 concurrent browsers without any performance issues.

The second server has the following specs:

[image]

As soon as it runs 2 browsers concurrently, the OS lags and slows down to being practically unusable.

The RAM and CPU usage are still at a minimum but attempting to open any other program while the browsers are running takes ~20 seconds.

I wonder what's causing this difference? No other programs are running on the servers.

Comment: What commands do you use to start those two browsers ?

Comment: What about Disk usage at the time?

Comment: @Prome Sorry for the late reply.
Disk usage is less than 5%.